# RAW JSON array - POST via Postman

Tags: arrays, json, postman

I am using postman to post an array to Firebase with a specific Authorization UID.
- Raw:

```html
{
"nGurKTPgFSVrAa5XaFHXAwpkKrE2": {
 "allergies" : "",
    "comment" : "",
    "company" : "",
    "customer_id" : "00002",
    "delivery_address" : "",
    "delivery_instruction" : "",
    "email" : "test+3@exampletesturlfortesting.com",
    "fallback" : "",
    "first_name" : "Bob",
    "last_name" : "Dylan",
    "membership" : 0,
    "mobile" : "",
    "password" : "example",
    "type" : 0
  }   
}
```

But in my database this creates a
[a new random ID under which it stores my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao0MU.jpg). What do I need to change so that it uses my UID to create the entry without nesting it into a new generated ID?

Comment: You can not defind UID If you are inserting new records. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data. The work around would be create your own uid in the record when you set them up.

Comment: @ChrisChen right! The above database is not the Authentication database though. Does that make a difference?

Besides: I can technically export the whole DB as JSON, add the entry manually in the exported JSON file and import it again (thus overwriting everything and including the above array properly). That works, but I naturally don't want to do that and am looking for a more efficient way.